# requirements.txt: any version < 1.5 (incl dev and rc versions)

Tags: python, pip, python-packaging

I am looking for a pattern for Python's requirement.txt (for usage with pip and python 3.10), which will cover all versions available up to a version 1.5, e.g.

- 1.4.2.dev5+g470a8b8
- 1.4.dev22+g2be722f
- 1.4
- 1.4rc0
- 1.5rc1

And: is there a clever way to test this without actually running "pip install" in a fresh venv?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to test with `python -m pip install --dry-run` without actually installing anything.

You can also install and test with [*`packaging`*](https://pypi.org/project/packaging/) which is the library used by *pip* internally.

I guess `!=1.5,<=1.5` should be what you want.

```py
import packaging.specifiers
import packaging.version

version_strings = [
    '1',
    '1.0'
    '1.1',
    '1.4',
    '1.4.2',
    '1.4.2.dev5+g470a8b8',
    '1.4.dev22+g2be722f',
    '1.4',
    '1.4rc0',
    '1.5rc1',
    '1.5',
    '1.5.1',
    '1.6',
    '2',
    '2.0',
]

versions = [packaging.version.Version(v) for v in version_strings]

specifier = packaging.specifiers.SpecifierSet('!=1.5,<=1.5', prereleases=True)

for version in versions:
    print(f'{version} in {specifier}: {version in specifier}')
```

```
$ python test.py 
1 in !=1.5,<=1.5: True
1.1.1 in !=1.5,<=1.5: True
1.4 in !=1.5,<=1.5: True
1.4.2 in !=1.5,<=1.5: True
1.4.2.dev5+g470a8b8 in !=1.5,<=1.5: True
1.4.dev22+g2be722f in !=1.5,<=1.5: True
1.4 in !=1.5,<=1.5: True
1.4rc0 in !=1.5,<=1.5: True
1.5rc1 in !=1.5,<=1.5: True
1.5 in !=1.5,<=1.5: False
1.5.post0 in !=1.5,<=1.5: False
1.5.0 in !=1.5,<=1.5: False
1.5.1 in !=1.5,<=1.5: False
1.6 in !=1.5,<=1.5: False
2 in !=1.5,<=1.5: False
2.0 in !=1.5,<=1.5: False
```

So you could use it like this:

```
python -m pip install --pre 'somepackage!=1.5,<=1.5'
```

or in a `requirements.txt` file:

```
--pre

somepackage !=1.5, <=1.5
```

***Related***:

- https://github.com/pypa/packaging/issues/617

Comment: so you must install with "pip -pre" as an equivalent to "prereleases=True"? Or can you define this in the requiremnents.txt as well?

Comment: Yes you need `--pre` somewhere. You can choose to add the `--pre` in the `requirements.txt` file. In this case it should be on its own line. See [doc](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/requirements-file-format/#global-options).

Comment: so the final solution for me would be to put this into the requirements.txt:

    somepackage <=1.5,!=1.5 --pre

Comment: I added an example of `requirements.txt` in the answer.

Comment: Unfortunately using "--pre" in requirements.txt does not work with setuptools (InvalidInvalidRequirement exception when building).

Comment: Does not work with *setuptools*? What do you mean? What are you trying to do?